# Can you use XCode6.3 with IOS7.1 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode6

Is it possible to use XCode6 beta with an IOS 7.1 SDK?  The new tools are much nicer but I need to build for IOS7

Comment: Did you try to set the deployment target? What happened? Keep in mind that you can't submit an App from a beta of Xcode.

Comment: Beta means any thing can happen and will happen. For production just use the latest stable version of Xcode... anything else will end in frustration.

Comment: Why you ask? You can have both Xcode 5 and 6 installed in parallel.

Comment: Can you build with the IOS7 SDK using Xcode6 beta?  You can build dfor IOS 6 with Xcode 5

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. 
1. First download 7.1 SDK - XCode6Beta > Preferences > Downloads > iOS 7.1 Simulator.

**Note:** XCode6-Beta can co-exist with regular XCode (XCode 5.x). But when you download iOS 7.1 Simulator, it actually gets downloaded into XCode 5's path!! (probably a bug).

1. Open XCode5's SDKs folder.. 
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
2. Open XCode6-beta's SDKs folder..
        /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
3. Copy iPhoneOS7.1.sdk from XCode5's to XCode6-Beta's SDK folder.
4. Restart XCode6-beta

Now if you go to Project's Build Settings, Base SDK, you will see 7.1 along with 8.0.

Enjoy![image]

Comment: It may not actually be a bug. Perhaps it's designed this way as to not have to download the SDK each time a beta is released. However maybe the bug is in Xcode 6 not finding the SDK in the Xcode 5 folder. Copy/paste the SDK worked for me.

Comment: It's not a bug.  iOS 7.1 SDK is not designed to be used in Xcode 6.  People have been hacking it in this way for years with other versions of Xcode and iOS.

Comment: This is not working for xCode 6.2. Any update on this ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using XCode6 and SDK version 8 regularly now, but I had to compile an app with version 7 of SDK, because version 8 was causing a lot of problems on devices with iOS8 installed, while in devices with iOS7 installed everything was running fine.. (!!)

I then:

- went to [XCode Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode)
- browsed through some pages in order to get the latest XCode 5 version and downloaded it
- opened the DMG with Image Mounter
- rightclicked XCode icon and selected "Show package contents"
- browsed Finder through Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
- copied iPhoneOS7.sdk and pasted it to /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
- restart XCode
- now you can select SDK 7.1 as the one to use in your project

this has immediately solved all of my issues with the app

Comment: Great for those who dont want to install XCode 5 again

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can copy the 7.1 SDK from the current Xcode distribution to the Xcode 6 Beta distribution like this:

```
cp -r /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

The example above will recursively copy the contents of the iPhoneOS7.1.sdk folder to the appropriate destination for Xcode6-Beta5 .  Copying the SDK to Xcode6-Beta6 would require adjusting the command line to point to the Xcode6-Beta6.app folder.

Answer (score 0):

So we had a very similar issue, our goal was to debug an issue that only appears on iOS 8 (with an app built in xCode 5 on the iOS 7.1 SDK). We were trying to use xCode 6, but found it too unstable, and then decided to go back to xCode 5 and debug using UIAlertNotifications (as we could previously not connect our iOS 8 device to xCode 5)

After connecting our iOS 8 device to xCode 6, when we re-opened xCode 5, our iOS 8 device was recognized and we were able to debug using NSLog statements (break points still caused our app to crash - making it apparent that the issues related to break points are with iOS 8 rather than xCode 6 as others have suggested)

I hope this info is of some help to others out there!